# Let S be the set of nonzero integers. Define a relation R on S by letting aRb mean that b/a is an integer. Is R an antisymmetric relation on S?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

A question from the back of my Discrete Math classes textbook. I cant think of any example where (a,b) belongs to R and (b,a) belongs to R but a $\neq$ b. 
The answer in the back literally just says "no".
This is my first question on here please be gentle.

Comment: Literally write out a few examples.  What do you observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! The answer is ''depends''.

Define the relation $aRb$ iff $a$ divides $b$, i.e., there exists $c$ with $a\cdot c=b$.

If the set on which the relation is defined is the set of integers, then $-1$ divides $1$ and $1$ divides $-1$, but $1\ne -1$.

If the set on which the relation is defined is the set of natural numbers, then the relation is antisymmetric.